# Reading XML in WinRT

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I know the web link of an XML file, and I'm using it in my app.

It's root element is `feed` and it has several child elements called `entry`. Each `entry` has an element `summary` which consists of both text and several child tags. For example,

```
<entry>
    <title type="text">money giving</title>
        <author>
        <name>BMA</name>
        </author>
    <summary type="text">
        <short-description>we give you money</short-description>
        <tab id="0" header="Header &amp; d">
        This is Line 1
        This is Line 2
        This is Line 3
        </tab>
        <tab id="1" header="abc">
        Only one line here
        </tab>
    </summary>
  </entry>
```

I want to get the complete text inside `summary`, including the child tags `short-description` and `tags`. I have tried using this code :

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri("http://bigmanani.com/Kiosk-RSS_updated.xml"));
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.GetXml());
XElement root = xDoc.Root;
XNamespace ad = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
IEnumerable<string> title = from abc in root.Descendants(ad+"summary") select (string )abc;

foreach(string one in title)
    DebugMessage(one);
```

The problem's that I get only the textual part of the `summary` element, and the child elements `short-description` and `tab` are ignored completely. How can I get the complete text instead ?

Comment: So what output are you seeing? I'd *expect* to see "we give you money This is Line 1 This is line 2 This is Line 3 Only one line here" - that would be consistent with the test I've just performed... If you expected to see the child element names and attributes, you shouldn't be casting to `string`.

Comment: That's the output but I also want the child tags included, so the output should be "<short-description>we give you money</short-descri..." i.e. the complete text within `summary`

Comment: Right, so don't cast to `string`. But bear in mind that's not "the complete text" as far as XML is concerned - it's a mixture of text nodes, element nodes, attributes etc. It's text if you think of XML as a string, but it's better to think of it as a tree of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just don't want the cast to string, which is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263) as:

> If the XElement has children, the concatenated string value of all of the element's text and descendant's text is returned.

You probably want [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005) instead:

> Returns the indented XML for this node.

So:

```
var title = root.Descendants(ad + "summary").Select(x => x.ToString());
```

(There's no benefit in using a query expression for just a simple projection - calling the extension method is simpler.)